# Singleton with Enum vs Singleton with double-checked locking

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I am wondering which one is better in practice in a multithreaded environment. I understand Singleton as Enum type creates an instance when the class is loaded. Other than that I don't see anything else significant. Is there any pros and cons ?

**Singleton as `Enum` type:**

```
 public enum Singleton {
      INSTANCE;
      public void doSomething(){ ... }
 }
```

**Singleton with `double-checked locking`:**

```
 public class Singleton{
      private volatile static Singleton instance;

      private Singleton(){}
      public static Singleton getInstance(){
           if(instance == null){
                 synchronized(Singleton.class){
                       if(instance == null){
                           instance = new Singleton();
                       }
                 }
           }
           return instance;
      }

 }
```

Comment: @DmitryBeransky This version is safe from 1.5, and in practice 1.4. But even 1.6 is facing its end-of-life. (I mean safe as in the exact code if thread-safe. It's unsafe in that it's easy to get wrong and the singleton may well be unsafe (certainly unwise).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often in multi-threaded applications, simpler, easier to understand code is more likley to work.

To my mind the first example is *significantly* simpler than the second and that is what matters.

The main pro of using an `enum` is its much simpler and the more complicated example is not justified.  The double locking example allows you to change the singleton in interesting way for unit tests, but I believe what this gives you can be solved another way.

Answer (score 2):

There are more problems with Singletons, than just a correct implementation.

People often use Singletons, so they don't have to pass Objects around, where they should or they would have to pass Objects across multiple Methods.

There are quite a few examples for instantiating a jdbc connection with a Singleton.

In the methods where you need this connection, you can easily access it, because its a Singleton.

```
public enum DBConnection {
  INSTANCE;
  private Connection connection;
  public Connection getConnection(){
    if(connection == null){
      instantiateConnection();
    }
    return connection;
  }
}
```

and accessing it by

```
DBConnection.INSTANCE.getConnection();
```

But often it's better to do it with Dependency Injection and a pleasent framework. GUICE for example.

In your code you would not make a call on DBConnection.INSTANCE and than on getConnection(), you're Class would have a field DBConnection annotated with @Inject. And you just use it.

```
@Inject
private DBConnection dBConnection;
```

And the Class would be just annotated with @Singleton to be a Singleton, and the framework would assure it's a singleton.

And if you have different environments like, test and production you could let the framework inject different Objects for each environment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `enum` for creating a `singleton` have gained popularity for being **simple and quick way to do it.**

Moreover you have compared here with Double check locking, **but then there are other ways too, without using enum.**

**eg:**

```
public class Test{

      private static Test uniqueInstance = new Test();

      private Test(){}

      public static Test getInstance(){


             return uniqueInstance;     
         }

 }
```

But i think `enum` makes quite a **straight forward approach with a cleaner self explained code for** `singleton`.